# climb ladder in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I'm relatively new to pygame and python as a whole, and I'm currently working on a school project.  I'm trying to make it so that when my Mario sprite is overlapping with the ladder sprite, he can move up, and when he's not overlapping, subsequently cannot move up.  Here's my code:

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import*
from Mario import Mario
from Ladder import Ladder

pygame.init()
game_over = False
dispwidth = 600
dispheight = 800
cellsize = 10
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
bg = white
mario = Mario([0, 800])
ladder = Ladder([600, 800])
mario2 = Mario.image
ladder2 = Ladder.image
mario_rect = mario2.get_rect()
ladder_rect = ladder2.get_rect()


'''def detectcollisions(x1, y1, w1, h1, x2, y2, w2, h2):

    if x2 + w2 >= x1 >= x2 and y2 + h2 >= y1 >= y2:
        return True

    elif x2 + w2 >= x1 + w1 >= x2 and y2 + h2 >= y1 >= y2:
        return True

    elif x2 + w2 >= x1 >= x2 and y2 + h2 >= y1 + h1 >= y2:
        return True

    elif x2 + w2 >= x1 + w1 >= x2 and y2 + h2 >= y1 + h1 >= y2:
        return True

    else:
        return False
    '''    


class Ladder(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    image = None

    def __init__(self, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        if Ladder.image is None:

            Ladder.image = pygame.image.load('Wood-ladder.png')
        self.image = Ladder.image

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottomright = location

        self.x = 499
        self.y = 420

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))


class Mario(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    image = None

    def __init__(self, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        if Mario.image is None:

            Mario.image = pygame.image.load('mario3.png')
        self.image = Mario.image

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottomleft = location

        self.x = 0
        self.y = 736

    def handle_keys(self):

        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys_pressed[K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= 5

        if keys_pressed[K_RIGHT]:
            self.x += 5

        while self.collide_rect(ladder):
            if keys_pressed[K_UP]:
                self.y -= 5

    def draw(self, surface):

        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))


def main():
    FPS = 30
    while not game_over:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys_pressed[K_LEFT]:
            mario.x -= 1

        if keys_pressed[K_RIGHT]:
            mario.x += 1

        if mario_rect.colliderect(ladder_rect):
            if keys_pressed[K_UP]:
                mario.y -= 5

        mario.handle_keys()
        screen.fill(bg)
        ladder.draw(screen)
        mario.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update()
        fpstime.tick(FPS)

while True:
    global fpstime
    global screen

    fpstime = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((dispwidth, dispheight))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Donkey Kong')
    main()
```

Comment: So what are your errors or what is not working exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with `pygame.Rect.colliderect` (you can also use `pygame.sprite.collide_rect(mario, ladder)`) but it can't work because you don't move the rects of the sprites which are used for the collision detection. You only change the `x` and `y` attributes (the blit position), but that doesn't affect the rects.

---

Handle the events either in the main loop or in the sprite, if you do both you'll move with increased speed because you handle the event twice.

You can put sprites in a `pygame.sprite.Group` a sprite group that will update and blit all contained sprites when you call `sprite_group.update()` and `sprite_group.draw(screen)`.

I've restructured your program to show you how I'd do it. The sprite group is an `OrderedUpdates` group because Mario should always appear over the ladder. There's still a problem with the ladders, when Mario is over the top of a ladder he can't move down again, but I'll let you figure that out. ;)

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


class Ladder(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    image = pygame.Surface((60, 300))
    image.fill(pygame.Color('blue'))

    def __init__(self, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(bottomleft=location)


class Mario(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    image = pygame.Surface((30, 50))
    image.fill(pygame.Color('red'))

    def __init__(self, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(bottomleft=location)


class Game:

    def __init__(self):
        self.fps = 30
        self.dispwidth = 600
        self.dispheight = 800
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.dispwidth, self.dispheight))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Donkey Kong')
        self.fpstime = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.white = (255, 255, 255)
        self.black = (0, 0, 0)
        self.mario = Mario([0, 600])
        self.ladder = Ladder([400, 600])
        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.OrderedUpdates(self.ladder, self.mario)
        self.game_over = False

    def run(self):
        while not self.game_over:
            self.handle_events()
            self.run_logic()
            self.draw()
            self.fpstime.tick(self.fps)

    def run_logic(self):
        self.all_sprites.update()

    def handle_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                self.game_over = True
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys_pressed[K_LEFT]:
            self.mario.rect.x -= 6
        if keys_pressed[K_RIGHT]:
            self.mario.rect.x += 6
        if keys_pressed[K_UP]:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self.mario, self.ladder):
                self.mario.rect.y -= 6
        if keys_pressed[K_DOWN]:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self.mario, self.ladder):
                self.mario.rect.y += 6

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.white)
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        pygame.display.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    Game().run()
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Just a quick question, where exactly is the sprite group?

Comment: I used the [OrderedUpdates](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.OrderedUpdates) group as sprite group. It's the `self.all_sprites` attribute of the `Game` class. OrderedUpdates is a special kind of sprite group that maintains the order of the added sprites. With a normal `pygame.sprite.Group` Mario could randomly appear behind or in front of the ladder.